# Checking radio buttons in different div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to check certain radio buttons on a webpage by looping over them all and trying to select the second value in each "group" of radio buttons, but I'm pretty confused on the syntax of it.

Everywhere that I've looked for documentation online has the "name" variable on each of the groups of the radio buttons the same to make each group easily accessible, but on this site that isn't the case and I'm getting stuck doing what seems like a simple solution.

I've been trying to get the "radX_ExtendedHold" radio button from each group checked in order to disable the "buttons footer class" at the bottom of the page until the user selects any different value from any of the groups of radio buttons. Here's the HTML code for it (this is not my site and I cannot edit the HTML to change the values of the names or anything):

```html
<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad0_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad0_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad0_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad0_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad1_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_21e7930b-31fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad1_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad1_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_21e7930b-31fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad1_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad2_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_d1b6d498-99da-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad2_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad2_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_d1b6d498-99da-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad2_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad3_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_3fe94663-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad3_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad3_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_3fe94663-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad3_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad4_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_f6fe26d5-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad4_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                           
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad4_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_f6fe26d5-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad4_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttonsFooter">
  <button type="submit" class="small_button_a">
            Proceed
        </button>
</div>
```

I've tried to get all of the elements within the "subsRenewEntry" class by using the following code:

```
$( ".subsRenewEntry" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
});
```

This seems to return the correct groups that I need. But it's just trying to check the second elements within each of the groups.

I've tried various methods to try and solve the problem which are as follows:

```
$( "rad" + index + "_ExtendedHold").filter('[value="ExtendedHold"]').prop('checked', true);

$('.screen-RenewSubscriptions_aspx').find('option[value="ExtendedHold"]').prop('checked', true);
```

But neither of them works.

I've also tried a different approach which works for single elements, which isn't too useful to me because I need the buttons to be dynamically allocated so it can be ran on any page with any X amount of radio button groups.

Anyway the code for that is as follows:

```
$('input:radio[name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39"]').filter('[value="ExtendedHold"]').attr('checked', true);
```

But again this only works for one of the buttons (obviously because the name is only equivalent to one of the names of the radio buttons).

I'm stil pretty new to javascript/jQuery and the syntax to access these variables seems to be tripping me up quite heavily on which seems to be an overall very simple solution. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very greatful. I'm not expecting someone to do the code for me, just some pointers on where I'm going wrong and how to change my thinking about it.

Comment: Your first approach of course finds nothing, because there are no elements with a _tag name_ starting with `rad...` - the ID selectors starts with `#`, remember? // Why not just select them by type and what parent structure they are in then …? Your two corresponding radio buttons are always grouped in a `.seriesOptions` element, so I would loop over those and then work on the radio buttons inside each one ...

Comment: Of course. Still getting used the selectors side of things within these languages. Coming from C based languages some things over here feel very alien.

I've tried this now and I can get all of the radio buttons to be checked to the right ones now so thanks a lot! That's much more progress than I've made in the past couple of days on my own.

Sorry to keep pressing the matter, but is there any functionality to say "if all of these are selected then do this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want every second checkbox value checked then please try below jquery code. Only this code will help you to do stuff. And you want different result then please comment here so i can try to solve them.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subsRenewEntry">                    
                    <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
                        <span>
                            <input id="rad0_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad0_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

                        <span>
                            <input id="rad0_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad0_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="subsRenewEntry">
                    <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
                        <span>
                            <input id="rad1_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_21e7930b-31fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad1_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>
                        </span>

                        <span>
                            <input id="rad1_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_21e7930b-31fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad1_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="subsRenewEntry">
                    <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
                        <span>
                            <input id="rad2_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_d1b6d498-99da-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad2_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

                        <span>
                            <input id="rad2_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_d1b6d498-99da-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad2_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="subsRenewEntry">
                    <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
                        <span>
                            <input id="rad3_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_3fe94663-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad3_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

                        <span>
                            <input id="rad3_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_3fe94663-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad3_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="subsRenewEntry">
                    <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
                        <span>
                            <input id="rad4_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_f6fe26d5-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad4_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                           
                        </span>

                        <span>
                            <input id="rad4_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_f6fe26d5-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad4_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>

        <div class="buttonsFooter">
        <button type="submit" class="small_button_a">
            Proceed
        </button>
    </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myarray = [];
    $( ".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span:nth-child(2) input[type=radio]").prop( "checked", true );
    var true_val= $('.subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span:nth-child(2) input[type=radio]').is(':checked');

    if(true_val==true) { 
            $('.buttonsFooter').hide();
    }   
    $(".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span input[type=radio]").change(function(){
         $(".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){
            var var_renewd= $(this).val();
            if(var_renewd=="Renewed"){
                $('.buttonsFooter').show();
            }
             myarray.push(var_renewd);              
         });            
        if(jQuery.inArray("Renewed", myarray) !== -1){
            $('.buttonsFooter').show();
        }else{
            $('.buttonsFooter').hide();
        }                       
        myarray=[];
    }); 
});
```

That code  will give you below url output.
https://www.screencast.com/t/uTBt2FtCFKkv

Comment: ` $( ".subsRenewEntry" ).each(function( index ) {
  $("#rad" + index + "_ExtendedHold").filter('[value="ExtendedHold"]').prop('checked', true);
  
 }); `

Seems to work and check all of the correct values that I need. I just need some follow up code that states "if all these values are selected then hide the "proceed" button. But I'm unsure how to get this value too or what the code would look like...

Comment: if all value has been selected as per my screen url then using jquery we can hide button and if value is not selected then we can enable process button.
You want this? Right ?

Comment: If "ExtendedHold" is selected for each value in the radio buttons then I want the proceed button to hide itself and then reappear if any value on the list is changed to "Renew".

Thank you so far!

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span:nth-child(2) input[type=radio]").prop( "checked", true );
  var true_val= $('.subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span:nth-child(2) input[type=radio]').is(':checked');
  
   if(true_val==true) { 
    $('.buttonsFooter').hide();
   }else{
    $('.buttonsFooter').show();
   }  
  $(".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span input[type=radio]").click(function(){
   $('.buttonsFooter').show();
  }); 
 });


can you try to put this script, that will do exactly what you said above. Please put it and check, and let me know.

Comment: please try my above code, i have change it as per your requirement.

Comment: if you have get your output then please can you mark answer as correct so i get more reputation ? Please..

Comment: Sorry been testing a few things. I can get the "proceed" button to hide itself using the following code:    if ($('#rad' + index + "_ExtendedHold").prop('checked')) {
   $(".buttonsFooter").hide();  But I can't get the button to reappear using   } else if($( '#rad' + index + "_Renewed").prop('checked')) {
   $(".buttonsFooter").show();  
  }  This is all done within the same function. because I use the index. I wonder if I need an event change listener instead? (I understand that your code is pretty different to how I'm doing things but this way seems simpler?)

Comment: I've changed my code to now replicate yours, and the button hides correctly on the page load, and now reappears when one of the options is changed, but I need it to disappear when all the options are set to "Extended hold" and reappear when  any option is changed and for it to continuously do this for as long as the user keeps changing the options.

Comment: I've edited the code a little further and managed to get the full functionality that I require. Thank you so much for your answers you've been super helpful! I'll mark your answer as correct :D Once again thank you so much, I've been stuck on this for days.

Comment: Hi again. It appears that my code only is really functional when theres only one set of radio buttons. When there are more than one and selections are changed in a certain way (i.e two options are set to "Renew" then set back to "ExtendedHold" the button doesn't disappear/reappear correctly. Is there any where else we can take this discussion? Feel like I'm flooding these comments now.

Comment: Hello, yes i can do a code as you said. You just want radio button when any one ans mark as Renew so i have to write only code for that.
I will make code for that and give you here.
Thank you for marking my ans as a correct. :)

Comment: Hello Niall, i try below code and here any of one radio is mark as a "Renew" then process button will show if all has been selected as "ExtendedHold" then button will gone. Let me know that will work for you or not?

Comment: $(".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span input[type=radio]").change(function(){$(".subsRenewEntry .seriesOptions span input[type=radio]:checked").each(function(){var var_renewd= $(this).val();if(var_renewd=="Renewed"){$('.buttonsFooter').show();}myarray.push(var_renewd);});if(jQuery.inArray("Renewed", myarray) !== -1){$('.buttonsFooter').show();}else{$('.buttonsFooter').hide();}myarray=[];});

i have added that code to above full code, so put as it is in  your page. And let me know if that is work or not.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for taking the time to come back to me today, I really appreciate that. I've tried using this code but I get "myArray is not defined".

Comment: I've got it fully working now, thank you so much for all of your help. You're a great scripter!

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), I think this will help you to get all the `.action...`:

```
$("input[type='radio'][name^=action_]")
```

or

```
$('input:radio[name^="action_"]')
```

*Note: since jQuery 1.6, you have [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to check your radio* `$(radioButton).prop("checked", true);`

---

```js
$("input[type='radio'][name^=action_]").filter('[value="ExtendedHold"]').attr('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad0_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad0_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad0_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_f5d61c45-69fc-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad0_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad1_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_21e7930b-31fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad1_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad1_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_21e7930b-31fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad1_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad2_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_d1b6d498-99da-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad2_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad2_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_d1b6d498-99da-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad2_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad3_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_3fe94663-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad3_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                            
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad3_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_3fe94663-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad3_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="subsRenewEntry">
  <div class="seriesOptions" data-default="Renewed">
    <span>
                            <input id="rad4_Renewed" type="radio" name="action_f6fe26d5-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="Renewed"  />
                            <label for="rad4_Renewed" >Yes, I want to renew now</label>                           
                        </span>

    <span>
                            <input id="rad4_ExtendedHold" type="radio" name="action_f6fe26d5-32fd-e711-8d62-000c2979ba39" value="ExtendedHold"  />
                            <label for="rad4_ExtendedHold" >Not sure, keep my seat for the time being</label>
                        </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="buttonsFooter">
  <button type="submit" class="small_button_a">
            Proceed
        </button>
</div>
```